# jQuery encodes square brackets in array param on $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, escaping, uri

There are 2 websites with jQuery library:

1. jQuery 1.7.
2. jQuery 1.10.

On both websites I making $.get request and pass array attribute ids:

```
jQuery.get('/my/url', { "ids": [1,2,3] });
```

On 1.10 version it's OK, generated request is:

```
http://domain.com/my/url?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3
```

But on 1.7 request looks like:

```
http://domain.com/my/url/?ids%255B%255D=1&ids%255B%255D=2&ids%255B%255D=3
```

As you see symbol % replaced with %25.
Any ideas why it happened?

There is list of all included JS-files in second website. Unfortunately I can't remove anything from this list on production website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/func.js?v=4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow/jquery.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow/efects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/et/currencymanager/et_currencymanager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/et/currencymanager/et_currencymanager_round.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/es/backcalls/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/es/backcalls/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Believe it or not, the two encodings are actually equivalent. The url encoding for the percent sign (%) is %25.

Try it here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

The second was probably put through a function that encodes every single character in a string, versus the first, which was most likely parsed to find which characters in the string needed to be encoded first.